# BrightScript function returning string sometimes returns itself (the function)

Tags: roku, brightscript

Sometimes when a BrightScript function, that is supposed to return `invalid` or a `string`, returns, it does not return either invalid nor a string, but instead it (seem as it) returns the type `Function`. I haven't been able to track down *why* or *when* but it seems pretty arbitrary a for the *when*.
This is such a function.

```
function RegRead(key, section = invalid)
  if section = invalid section = "Default"
  sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection",section)
  if sec.Exists(key)
    return sec.Read(key)
  end if
  return invalid
end function
```

I call it something like this

```
val = RegRead("code")
```

What's going on? Is this a BrightScript bug?

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found the culprit: name clashing. I had functions like

```
function Code()
    ' bla bla bla
end function
```

...which meant that I could NOT have samely named variables somewhere else in that same script.

Having the function above named Code, I could not do this somewhere else:

```
sub Somethingelse()
    code = FetchValue()
end sub
```

Since the variable name `code` would clash with the function `Code()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here the calling the function

```
m.top.GlobleURL = GetAuthData() ' Call Read Function in Globle Variable
print "Read URL : " + m.top.GlobleURL 
SetAuthData(Serverurl)  ' Call write Function in Seturl
```

'Here the Read function

```
Function GetAuthData() As Dynamic
' reg = CreateObject("roRegistry")
 sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "Authentication")
' print "section : " + Authentication
 if sec.Exists("Authentication")
  print "Read URL : " + m.top.GlobleURL
  print " ****************** DATA :" + m.top.GlobleURL
  return sec.Read("Authentication")
 'return sec.Delete("Authentication") ' Here not override concept so compalsary delete first and after again second URL Store pannel.brs and hud.brs both file

 print "***********************GetAuthData************************"
 endif

 return invalid
End Function
```

Here the write function

```
Function SetAuthData(Serverurl As String) As Void
' reg = CreateObject("roRegistry")
 sec = CreateObject("roRegistrySection", "Authentication")
 m.top.GlobleURL = Serverurl
' if not m.top.GlobleURL = Serverurl 
sec.Write("Authentication", m.top.GlobleURL)
?"key for the URL" sec.GetKeyList()

    Print "Write URL :" + m.top.GlobleURL
' end if

 print "***********************SetAuthData************************"

' Flush(true)

End Function
```

you always pass with the argument in a function at that calling time pass as an argument and not pass any argument at the write of a function then simply declare one variable and initialize it.